# Exclude null values in column while using windows partition by column in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame like below in `pyspark`.

```
+-----+---+---+----+
|tests|val|asd|cnty|
+-----+---+---+----+
|test1|  Y|  1|null|
|test2|  N|  2|  UK|
| null|  Y|  1|  UK|
|test1|  N|  2|null|
| null|  N|  3|null|
|test3|  N|  4| AUS|
|test4|  Y|  5|null|
+-----+---+---+----+
```

I want to update the `val` column when the any given `tests` has `val Y` then all `val's` of that particular `tests` should be updated to `Y`. if not then what ever values they have. I want to exclude the records where `tests` column has `null` values.

I have done like below

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as f


df1 = df.select('tests', f.max('val').over(Window.partitionBy('tests')).alias('val'), 'asd', 'cnty')
```

I am getting result like below

```
+-----+---+---+----+
|tests|val|asd|cnty|
+-----+---+---+----+
|test1|  Y|  1|null|
|test1|  Y|  2|null|
|test2|  N|  2|  UK|
|test3|  N|  4| AUS|
|test4|  Y|  5|null|
| null|  Y|  1|  UK|
| null|  Y|  3|null|
+-----+---+---+----+
```

I want the result to be like below

```
+-----+---+---+----+
|tests|val|asd|cnty|
+-----+---+---+----+
|test1|  Y|  1|null|
|test1|  Y|  2|null|
|test2|  N|  2|  UK|
|test3|  N|  4| AUS|
|test4|  Y|  5|null|
| null|  Y|  1|  UK|
| null|  N|  3|null|
+-----+---+---+----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you needed was an additional `when` condition checking

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df1 = df.select('tests', f.when((f.isnull(f.col('tests'))) | (f.col('tests') == 'null'), f.col('val')).otherwise(f.max('val').over(Window.partitionBy('tests'))).alias('val'), 'asd', 'cnty')
```

which would give you

```
+-----+---+---+----+
|tests|val|asd|cnty|
+-----+---+---+----+
|test4|  Y|  5|null|
|test3|  N|  4| AUS|
|test1|  Y|  1|null|
|test1|  Y|  2|null|
|test2|  N|  2|  UK|
| null|  Y|  1|  UK|
| null|  N|  3|null|
+-----+---+---+----+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: I have used the same data the `OP` has used Here is the code `data = [("test1", "Y", 1, "null"),
("test2", "N", 2, "UK"),
(" null", "Y", 1, "UK"),
("test1", "N", 2, "null"),
(" null", "N", 3, "null"),
("test3", "N", 4, "AUS"),
("test4", "Y", 5, "null")]


df = sc.parallelize(data).toDF(["tests", "val", "asd", "cnty"])` and I have used your answer to get the result

Comment: if you look closely at `(" null", "Y", 1, "UK")` row then there is a space at the front of null. thats causing the issue